# How to create a grid layout system like bootstrap in Angular Material?

Tags: angular-material, angular7, angular-material-7

We have used Angular Material version 7 to developed the application. Here we try to implement the grid layout system like in bootstrap but there is no option to implement grid layout system. I tried with some custom CSS but it is suitable for all devices. So please share on your thoughts on this

Referal Link:

https://material.angular.io/components/categories/layout

Thanks in advance,

Subash Ravi

Comment: Try https://github.com/angular/flex-layout. Not a "grid" system specifically, but a very flexible layout system and probably the most popular one for Angular Material.

Comment: Why you don't want to use grid list? https://material.angular.io/components/grid-list/overview. It looks like it suits your needs. You can also just use bootstrap next to the Angular Material.

Comment: I would caution against using grid list. It is not intended to be used as a layout tool - It is a list component that uses a grid layout. For very simple things it might be okay, but it isn't easy to use in a flexible manner. It is mainly intended for laying out grid tiles.